# NSUserDefaults save and read in tableview as an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

ok so I have the user input a name into a textfield and a button passes the name to a tableview in another view, the table view lists the name but when a new name is added it overwrites the previous name instead of listing all names added to the tableview. here is my code:

viewcontroller1:

```
     @IBAction func addPlant(sender: AnyObject) {



        let array = self.title
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "userName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

viewcontroller2:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var ourText = String()

var textArray:[String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //self.tableview.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    ourText = userDefaults.stringForKey("userName")!
    textArray.append(ourText)



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return textArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. If your viewdidload of viewcontroller2 is called after you set the nsuserdefaults, you are basically appending it to an empty array. Do the appending in viewcontroller1 before you save it to userdefaults.

Comment: @NitinAlabur What I am wanting is to save names in one view controller and load them into viewcontroller 2 where they will display in a table view. I am able to input one name and for it to display but i am needing an unlimited amount of names to be input and displayed as a list.

Comment: put log statements at each step and see where each one is called. your code doesn't give enough context as to when a viewcontroller is presented. are these in two tabs? is vc1 presenting/pushing vc2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 textArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("userName")
```

Or

```
 textArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName")
```